# JSON deserializing in VB.NET, understanding objects

Tags: .net, json, vb.net, serialization, deserialization

I am using an online API to gather movie information. The information is downloaded in JSON format. I understand that this has to be 'unserialized' so that it can be read in a format VB.NET understands. I have managed to do so, as shown below:

```
Imports System.Web.Script.Serialization

Public Class Form1

Dim serializer As JavaScriptSerializer

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    serializer = New JavaScriptSerializer()
End Sub

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim json
    Dim cast1
    Dim objXMLHTTP
    Dim urltxt
    urltxt = "http://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/" + IDText.Text + "/casts?api_key=***"
    objXMLHTTP = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
    objXMLHTTP.open("GET", urltxt, False)
    objXMLHTTP.send()

    If objXMLHTTP.Status = 200 Then
        json = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(objXMLHTTP.ResponseBody)
    Else
        json = ""
    End If

    Dim result As Object = serializer.Deserialize(Of Object)(json)
    cast1 = result.Item("cast")(0)("name")
    Label1.Text = cast1

End Sub

End Class
```

So, when the form loads, a JavaScriptSerializer is initiated. Then, on the form, a user types in the id no. of a movie, and click `Button1`. On this event, the variable `urltxt` is defined with the `movie id` entered. Then I am not sure how the `objXMLHTTP` part works. I understand that the data retrieved is made up of a stream of bytes, and so the `ResponseBody` must be converted to ASCII. For an id value of 550, the id for Fight Club, I get this JSON response in return (Note: for the most part this data is consistent, so don't bother going over it all):

```
200 (OK)
Content-Type: application/json

{
"id": 550,
"cast": [
    {
        "id": 819,
        "name": "Edward Norton",
        "character": "The Narrator",
        "order": 0,
        "profile_path": "/7cf2mCVI0qv2PnZVNbbEktS8Xae.jpg"
    },
    {
        "id": 287,
        "name": "Brad Pitt",
        "character": "Tyler Durden",
        "order": 1,
        "profile_path": "/w8zJQuN7tzlm6FY9mfGKihxp3Cb.jpg"
    },
    {
        "id": 1283,
        "name": "Helena Bonham Carter",
        "character": "Marla Singer",
        "order": 2,
        "profile_path": "/s5WtwCxOuPR3aIYYZ06Cof7tw2A.jpg"
    },
    {
        "id": 7470,
        "name": "Meat Loaf",
        "character": "Robert 'Bob' Paulson",
        "order": 3,
        "profile_path": "/AsYkaWwsNCxORU372t0isSDDyad.jpg"
    },
    {
        "id": 7471,
        "name": "Zach Grenier",
        "character": "Richard Chesler",
        "order": 4,
        "profile_path": "/vtKQjYDLvx8AhUZtyYS61pU7DRF.jpg"
    },
    {
        "id": 7472,
        "name": "Richmond Arquette",
        "character": "Intern",
        "order": 5,
        "profile_path": null
    },
    {
        "id": 7219,
        "name": "David Andrews",
        "character": "Thomas",
        "order": 6,
        "profile_path": "/957tUR5s9FV3J25ruGmjQD8rD7A.jpg"
    },
    {
        "id": 7473,
        "name": "Rachel Singer",
        "character": "Chloe",
        "order": 7,
        "profile_path": "/aYlqeJIrFmbRAScxqhBSPVrG2pX.jpg"
    },
    {
        "id": 7497,
        "name": "Holt McCallany",
        "character": "The Mechanic",
        "order": 8,
        "profile_path": "/1xR6O1dkKDJ9ypurlKfQ1qqHv4n.jpg"
    },
    {
        "id": 7498,
        "name": "Eion Bailey",
        "character": "Ricky",
        "order": 9,
        "profile_path": "/aqDGV2NWABCnENOlPrd2lchs45n.jpg"
    },
    {
        "id": 7499,
        "name": "Jared Leto",
        "character": "Angel Face",
        "order": 10,
        "profile_path": "/9jZCWhSx8NU3VHB6TRzUvgWQK3I.jpg"
    },
    {
        "id": 7500,
        "name": "Peter Iacangelo",
        "character": "Lou",
        "order": 11,
        "profile_path": null
    }
],
"crew": [
    {
        "id": 7469,
        "name": "Jim Uhls",
        "department": "Writing",
        "job": "Author",
        "profile_path": null
    },
    {
        "id": 7474,
        "name": "Ross Grayson Bell",
        "department": "Production",
        "job": "Producer",
        "profile_path": null
    },
    {
        "id": 7475,
        "name": "Ceán Chaffin",
        "department": "Production",
        "job": "Producer",
        "profile_path": null
    },
    {
        "id": 1254,
        "name": "Art Linson",
        "department": "Production",
        "job": "Producer",
        "profile_path": null
    },
    {
        "id": 7476,
        "name": "David Prior",
        "department": "Production",
        "job": "Producer",
        "profile_path": null
    },
    {
        "id": 7477,
        "name": "John King",
        "department": "Sound",
        "job": "Original Music Composer",
        "profile_path": null
    },
    {
        "id": 7478,
        "name": "Michael Simpson",
        "department": "Sound",
        "job": "Original Music Composer",
        "profile_path": null
    },
    {
        "id": 7479,
        "name": "Jeff Cronenweth",
        "department": "Camera",
        "job": "Director of Photography",
        "profile_path": null
    },
    {
        "id": 7480,
        "name": "James Haygood",
        "department": "Editing",
        "job": "Editor",
        "profile_path": null
    },
    {
        "id": 7481,
        "name": "Laray Mayfield",
        "department": "Production",
        "job": "Casting",
        "profile_path": null
    },
    {
        "id": 1303,
        "name": "Alex McDowell",
        "department": "Art",
        "job": "Production Design",
        "profile_path": null
    },
    {
        "id": 7763,
        "name": "Ren Klyce",
        "department": "Sound",
        "job": "Sound Editor",
        "profile_path": null
    },
    {
        "id": 7764,
        "name": "Richard Hymns",
        "department": "Sound",
        "job": "Sound Editor",
        "profile_path": null
    },
    {
        "id": 7467,
        "name": "David Fincher",
        "department": "Directing",
        "job": "Director",
        "profile_path": "/iTWJyV1yUoagqDzxyTjxoPuSVs.jpg"
    },
    {
        "id": 7468,
        "name": "Chuck Palahniuk",
        "department": "Writing",
        "job": "Novel",
        "profile_path": "/8nOJDJ6SqwV2h7PjdLBDTvIxXvx.jpg"
    }
]
}
```

After this, the contents of the variable json is deserialized. This is the part I would most like to understand. Exactly what kind of object is being created? And how does the Item property work? I would like to understand this so I can count the number of elements in the 'cast' element of the JSON data. I know that the code works because using the `result.Item("cast")(0)("name")` function returns "Edward Norton", which is correct.

Answer (score 0):

The deserilzed object is a type that has the correct properties. You can generate a class/classes for example from a valid json using the follwing link: http://json2csharp.com/.
For your example would be:

```
public class Cast
{
  public int id { get; set; }
  public string name { get; set; }
  public string character { get; set; }
  public int order { get; set; }
  public string profile_path { get; set; }
}

public class Crew
{
  public int id { get; set; }
  public string name { get; set; }
  public string department { get; set; }
  public string job { get; set; }
  public string profile_path { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
  public int id { get; set; }
  public List<Cast> cast { get; set; }
  public List<Crew> crew { get; set; }
}
```

So basically you can create your classes with the correct properties and the deserializer creates instances of your concrete types if the mappings are correct. The Json and the classes you define should match.